# Specific inner product fo space $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ with desired properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ as vector space of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ and differential operator $\dfrac{d}{dx}:\mathbb{R}_n[x]\to \mathbb{R}_n[x]$. Is it possible to equip $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ with inner product in order to make this operator skew-symmetric?

**Remark:** By skew-symmetric I mean the following: An operator $f:V\to V$ is called skew-symmetric if $f^*=-f$, i.e. $(f(x),y)=-(x,f(y))$ for all $x,y\in V$.

**My approach:** Suppose it is possible to equip $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ with such inner product then it follows that $(\frac{df}{dx},f)=0.$ In particular it follows that $(x^m,x^{m+1})=0$ for all $0\leq m<n$.

Probably I have to use some property of skew-symmetric operators. For example, I know that for any such operator one can find an orthonormal basis such that the matrix of operator in this basis is block-diagonal with $2\times 2$ blocks $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a \\
-a & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $1\times 1$ zero blocks.

I would be very thankful if someone can show the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.  In particular, if $\frac {d}{dx}$ were skew-symmetric with respect to some inner product, it would follow that its matrix (with respect to some relatively orthonormal basis) unitarily diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.  However, $\frac{d}{dx}$ is nilpotent and non-zero and therefore cannot be diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! But let me clarify some moments. Skew-symmetric operator may not be diagonalizable but you claimed that it is diagonalizable. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: @ZFR every skew-Hermitian operator (over a complex vector space, or over the complexifcation of a real vector space) is unitarily diagonalizable, as is guaranteed by the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case) (note that skew-symmetric operators are normal).

Comment: Yes you are right and i know this fact but the i am a bit confused not in this. But we are assuming that our operator is skew symmetric and somehow you begin to consider skew hermitian? Could you explain this transition?

Comment: An operator over a real vector space is skew-symmetric if and only if it is Hermitian

Comment: Let me ask you probably a dumb question: we know that skew-hermitian operators are diagonalizable but skew-symmetric may not be. Then by your reasoning it follows that any skew-symmetric is diagonalizable, right? Am i misunderstanding smth?

Comment: Any skew symmetric operator on a real vector space is diagonalizable over the complexification of that vector space. An operator on a complex vector space which is skew symmetric relative to a bilinear (rather than sesqui-linear) scalar product will not necessarily be diagonalizable.

Comment: In any case we can avoid the apparently problematic discussion of a space’s complexifocation by noting the following. If $A$ is a skew symmetric operator over a real space, then $A^2$ is symmetric and therefore diagonalizable. However in the case of your operator, the square of your operator is not diagonalizable (for $n>1$, anyway), which means that your operator can’t be skew symmetric.

Comment: Another observation that works here: if $A$ is skew symmetric, then $A$ and $A^2=-A^TA$ must have the same rank. This does not hold for your operator, so your operator can not be skew symmetric.

Comment: Your reasoning with $A^2$ is much easire and nicer. I have seen complexification before in my lectures but i did not get the idea behind it. Do you know any book which has good explanation about it?

Comment: A good substitute for talking about complexifications is talking about matrices. Every operator on a finite dim real inner product space can be represented as a matrix with the adjoint corresponding to the transpose. That matrix has exactly the same properties, however, if we think of it as an operator on a complex inner product space with the adjoint corresponding to the conjugate-transpose

Comment: I liked the explanation given in Brian c hall’s text on matrix Lie groups and Lie algebras, but honestly most of my intuition on this comes from the reasoning that I outline in the previous comment.

Comment: I have spent some time trying to digest what you wrote. Your reasoning with $A^2$ is very nice and it works for $n>1$. But if $n=1$ then we have 2-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}_1[x]$ and the differential operator has rank $1$ because in basis $\{1,x\}$ the matrix of differential operator is $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\ 0&0
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.

Comment: But if there is inner product which makes this operator skew symmetric then there is canonical basis such that matrix of this operator in this basis is block diagonal with blocks $0$ or $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
0&-a\\ a&0
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.  But it means that the rank should be even, i.e. $0$ or $2$. This is contradiction. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I did not notice one of your comments, where you stated that if $A$ is skew-symmetric matrix then ranks of $A$ and $A^2$ are the same. To be honest it is quite interesting fact which I have never seen before. If $A$ is skew symmetric then $A$ is normal matrix and we know than normal matrices are diagonalizable in $\mathbb{C}$. If follows that $D=P^{-1}AP$ for some diagonal matrix $D$ and $P$ nonsingular. Then $A=PDP^{-1}$ and $A^2=PD^2P^{-1}$ and $\text{rank}A=\text{rank}D=\text{rank}D^2=\text{rank}A^2$. Right?

Comment: @ZFR that would be a valid proof, yes. However, I was appealing to the fact that $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same rank for any real matrix $A$

Comment: But in the fact which you mentioned you are not using that $A$ is skew symmetric right? The proof that ranks of $A$ and $A^TA$ are the same does not rely on skew-symmetricity.

Comment: Ohh yeah i was wrong... sorry. You are using skew symmetric property in order to show that $A^2=-A^TA$ and rank of $A$ is $n-1$ but rank of $A^2$ is $n-2$.

Comment: @ZFR Yes, that's exactly what I meant